# Show that $T$ is the Set of All Sets Using the ZF Axioms

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let x be a set. Define the "set" $S = \left\{ y:x\subseteq y \right\}$ and $T = \cup\left\{y:y\in S \right\}$. Given any set $w$, let $z=x \cup \left\{w\right\}$.

Then $x \subseteq z$, so $z \in S$.
But $w \in z$, so $w \in T$.

I'm supposed to be able to conclude that $T$ happens to be the "set of all sets", but I have no idea how to do this and I do not understand the last sentence above this one beginning with "but".

Please offer some insight to me. Thank you

Comment: if $x=\{1,2,3\}$ then $\{1,2\}\notin T$ so $T$ is not the set of all sets

Comment: @Jon: You’re mistaken. $\{1,2\}\notin S$, but $\{1,2\}\in T$. In fact, $$\{1,2\}\in\big\{1,2,3,\{1,2\}\big\}\in S\;,$$ so $\{1,2\}\in\bigcup S=T$.

Comment: $x\notin \{1,2,3,\{1,2\}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’re starting with an arbitrary set $w$, with the goal of showing that $w\in T$. Since $$T=\bigcup\{y:y\in S\}\;,$$ this means that we want to find a $z\in S$ such that $w\in z$.

Set $z=x\cup\{w\}$. Clearly $x\subseteq z$, so by definition $z\in S$. But on the other hand $w\in z$: the members of $z$ are $w$ and the members of $x$. Thus, we’ve found a $z\in S$ such that $w\in z$, and by the definition of union we have $$w\in\bigcup\{y:y\in S\}=T\;.$$

Since $w$ was an arbitrary set, it follows that $T$ contains every set as an element.

As an example, suppose, as **Jon Mark Perry** suggested in the comments, that $x=\{1,2,3\}$ and $w=\{1,2\}$. Then we set

$$z=x\cup\{w\}=\big\{1,2,3,\{1,2\}\big\}\;;$$

the elements of $z$ are $1,2,3$ (the elements of $x$) and $\{1,2\}$. Thus, $w=\{1,2\}\in z$. Moreover, $x=\{1,2,3\}\subseteq z$, so $z\in S$. That is, $w\in z\in S$, and therefore by definition $w\in\bigcup\{y:y\in S\}$: there’s at least one member of $S$ that contains $w$ as an element.